# unable to store in globals from a firestore call

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

real flutter/firestore beginner here and I'm really getting confused.Basically in my app i'm storing variables in a globals file, it works everytime except here. I'm retrieving a jobID value from a Firestore field, and i'm trying to store it in my globals jobID variable:

Here is the code:

```
   
      databaseReference.collection("counters").doc("jobs").get().then((value){
    var jobID = value.data()["jobsID"];
    print("jobID is $jobID");
    globals.update("jobID",(value) => jobID);

  });
```

Comment: JobId or JobsId?   var jobID = value.data()["jobsID"];

Comment: jobsID (with an s) is the field in my firebase document, JobID (with an S) is the variable i Use in my code, and in the globals – juloni 10 mins ago   Delete

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
I have an issue with my data type, will look into it, closing this case for now